# How can I use a WKT as an input to a function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial

I have the following where clause in a t-sql statement:

```
where a.CELL_GEOM.STIntersects(
STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-25.43623984375 44.257784519021, 21.62918984375 44.257784519021, 21.62918984375 60.752403080295, -25.43623984375 60.752403080295, -25.43623984375 44.257784519021))', 4326)) = 'true'
```

The line reports the error:

```
'STGeomFromText' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

How can I use the well known text value shown in this function? Am I just using incorrect syntax with the STGeomFromText as that is the only example I have seen.

Comment: What happens if you prefix the name of the function with `geometry::` like in the documentation? E.g. `geometry::STGeomFromText( ...`

Comment: That fixed it. Totally didnt think to put that in. Thanks.

Comment: That easy eh? I'll post as an answer!

Comment: Yeah pretty unbelievable that I didnt spot that. It been a long hard road using spatial with SQL Server :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try prefixing the name of the function with `geometry::` like in the documentation?

E.g. : `geometry::STGeomFromText( ...`

[Link to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx)